# Accessing AJAX JSON properties with index gives undefined in the promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, mongodb

So I have quiz app which is talking to my API on the server with MongoDB.

I want to access its response indexes like so:

```
setTimeout(() => {

  axios.get('/api/ninjas')
    .then(function (questions) {
      var data = questions.data;


  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    /*thequestion = [
      new Question(value.the_question[index], value.the_choices[index], value.the_answer[index])

    ]*/
    console.log(value[index].the_question);
    quiz = new Quiz(thequestion)
    populate()
  })
}), 2000});
```

But I get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'the_question' of undefined`

If I remove the `[index]` then I get the question text out in the console. I also tried putting `[index]` in the end like so `console.log(value.the_question[index]);` but then I just get one letter at the time in the screen.

So basically I have two objects in my MongoDB collection. Each contains the_question string, the_choices array and the_answer string. I want to output one question at a time in the screen and its answer choices, but when I reload the page I get only the last question in the DB collection and all answer choices at a time stacked right after each other, even tho there should be no more than 3 buttons for each question. When there is only one question in DB it works fine.

One question in DB:

[image]

More than one question in DB collection:

[image]

So I want to use indexes to output one question at a time, but I get error when using them. What's wrong?

I have to mention that it was working fine I wasn't using DB for this. Just globals in javascript. Like this, I was getting one question at a time

```
let thequestion = [
  new Question("Which one of the three is a programming language?", ["Javascript", "HTML", "CSS"], "Javascript"),
  new Question("Is NodeJS is a front end or back end framework?", ["Back end", "Front End"], "Back end"),
  new Question("Is JAVA object oriented language?", ["Yes", "No"], "Yes")
]
```

My DB looks like this:

[image]

EDIT: The whole front-end source code:

https://codepen.io/Limpuls/pen/rYYLro?editors=1010

Comment: Should be `value.the_question` and loop over array `value.choices`

Comment: ... or `data[index].the_question`

Comment: @charlietfl I used `value.the_question` by default and that's when I was getting only the last question on the screen and choices of both first and the last question. Should I loop inside the ajax function? Because I tried to loop inside `populate()` function like so: `for (var i = 0; i < value.choices.length; i++) {...` but then I get: `script.js:100 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: value is not defined
    at populate (script.js:100)`

Comment: That loop would be inside the other `each` loop

Comment: @charlietfl value.choices is not an array. Did you mean value.the_choices?

Comment: Yes... `value.the_choices`. It was a typo on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following, if that doesn't work could you please update your question with the output of the console log so we can see the format of the questions received by your API?

```
setTimeout(() => {
  axios.get('/api/ninjas')
  .then(function (questions) {
    console.log(
      "received questions:"
      ,JSON.stringify(questions,undefined,2)
    );
    quiz = new Quiz(//create a quiz
      (questions.data || [])//map question data to Question type
      .map(
        function (question) {
          return new Question(
            question.the_question, 
            question.the_choices, 
            question.the_answer
          );
        }
      )
    );
    populate()
  })
  , 2000
});
```

Why are you waiting 2 seconds to get the data? If this is on page load then you could try `$(document).ready` but I don't think you have to wait for document ready to start fetching the questions (maybe  only populate):

```
$(document).ready(x=>populate());
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response,it worked totally fine, thank you. I still do not get how is your version different to mine. Before trying your code out, I had came up with this https://codepen.io/Limpuls/pen/XzqzEp?editors=0010 like what a hell, it does totally the same thing and it works, I get one question at a time in order from the first one to the last, but answer choices buttons still get all populated at a time (if there are 2 questions in DB with 3 answers for each question, then I get 6 answer buttons for each question, instead of 3). The only difference I see, that you use map

Comment: @Limpuls A quiz takes an array of questions, in your code you create a new quiz for each question. In the map I take all question data and map them to an array of `Question` then pass that array of questions to `new Quiz`

Comment: Oh, I didn't see this small mistake. Thanks!